# Тип сказуемого в предложении (2)

Tags: синтаксис

В предложении-фрагменте, взятом из произведения А. П. Чехова "О любви", **"...не занимался наукой или чем-нибудь другим, что делало бы его жизнь более приятной..."** сказуемым будет являться сочетание ***делало бы более приятной***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***…что делало бы его жизнь более приятной.***

**Что** – подлежащее, **делало бы** – сказуемое, **делало бы** (что?) – жизнь, дополнение,  **делало бы  жизнь** (какой?) более приятной (определение).

Глагол задает  В.п. дополнению «жизнь» и Т.п. определению «более приятной» , также определение согласуется в роде и числе с дополнением. Таким образом, определение является **дуплексивом** (словом **с двунаправленной связью**).

Соответственно, глагол «делать»  нельзя в данном случае считать связкой  в именном сказуемом, так как **нет однонаправленной связи** подлежащее – сказуемое.

Сравнить:  ***Жизнь делается (становится)  более приятной.***  Делается более приятной – составное именное сказуемое.

Из словаря: **ДЕЛАТЬ**, 4. из кого-чего. Обращать, превращать в кого-, что-л. Д. из кого-л. посмешище.  // (кем-чем, **каким**). Приводить в какое-л. состояние или положение; придавать какой-л. вид. Д. кого-л. своим помощником. **Д. кого-л. несчастным.** Очки делали его смешным.